# AlarmManager не срабатывает после перезагрузки телефона

Tags: java, android

У меня проблема, мой AlarmManager  после перезагрузки не показывает уведомление через нужный промежуток времени, без перезагрузки всё отлично работает.

Метод создания AlarmManager:

```
  private void addAlarmNotification(long startTime, String title, String text){
    AlarmManager alarmManager;

    PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("text", text);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int)startTime, intent, 0);

    //alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, 0, alarmIntent);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, alarmIntent);
}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
 if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT) ) {
            DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
            List<Plant> plants = databaseHandler.getAllPlants();

            for(Plant plant: plants){
                if (plant.getStage() != Util.STAGE[3]) {
                    System.out.println(plant.toString());
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.setTime(new Date(Long.parseLong(plant.getStartData())));
                    switch (plant.getStage()) {
                        case 0:
                            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
                            addAlarmNotification(context, c.getTimeInMillis(), plant.getName(), "Нужно снять крышку");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
                            addAlarmNotification(context, c.getTimeInMillis(), plant.getName(), "Нужно полить ваше растение");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
                            addAlarmNotification(context, c.getTimeInMillis(), plant.getName(), "Сбор урожая");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    try {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, PlantActivity.class);
        PlantActivity.name = intent.getStringExtra("title");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

       
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_splash)
                .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("title"))
                .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("text"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setLights(0x0000FF, 3000, 2000)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(56, builder.build());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Код в AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: А где ваш код, который реагирует на `BOOT_COMPLETED`? Он должен выставлять AlarmManager заново.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Добрый день, не знал об этом, не подскажите как это нужно сделать?

Comment: В `onReceive` проверяйте что за action у интента. Так поймете это перезагрузка или таймер сработал. Пример: https://riptutorial.com/android/example/15019/broadcastreceiver-to-handle-boot-completed-events

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Да я уже нашел, попробовал при action  if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) ) вывести уведомление, ожидал что оно будет после перезагрузки, однако оно сработало когда я после перезагрузки зашел в приложение.

Comment: После установки надо хотя бы один раз запустить приложение. Тут еще другие условия описаны: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32032475/5479247

Comment: К сожалению даже если вошел и перезагрузил нужно сначала войти в приложение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109244/discussion-between-pavlo-pavlov-and-eugene-krivenja).

Comment: На Xiaomi нужно установить разрешение на автозагрузку!

Comment: @Style-7 Добрый день, вот же установлено, или нужно что-то еще?<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

Comment: сам пользователь устанавливает

Answer (score 1):

Только что прогнал тест на эмуляторе API 28, `BOOT_COMPLETED` отлично работает.
**Манифест**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Получатель**

```
class BootReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "BOOT_COMPLETED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

После перезагрузки все прилетает как и должно.

Comment: Тестировал у себя на Xiaomi api23, не хочет, в эмуляторе проверил работает, спасибо за ваш ответ.