# Отправка уведомлений по дням недели

Tags: android, android-notification, android-alarm-manager

Нужно, чтобы приложение отправляло уведомление, к примеру, только по понедельникам в определенное время. Для этого лучше использовать `AlarmManager` или `Notification` или `Push-notification` или есть более лучший способ реализации этого? Буду рад любым предложениям.

Comment: Если время показа уведомления критично, то только AlarmManager. Если нет можно сделать через WorkManager например, а он под капотом сам определит, что использовать.

Comment: Но насколько я знаю AlarmManager пропадает после перезагрузки устройства. Можно ли как-то избежать этого?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1140009/452965 ответ есть